# How do I take a screenshot on a Mac?

Tags: macos, keyboard, screen-capture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I take a screenshot on my Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3822/how-do-i-take-a-screenshot-on-my-mac)

I haven't found any shortcut or application on my Mac which provide such functionality.

I would like to know the keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>-<kbd>3</kbd> will save a screenshot of the whole screen to your desktop. <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Control ⌃</kbd>-<kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>-<kbd>3</kbd> copies it to your clipboard.
- <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>⇧</kbd>-<kbd>4</kbd> lets you drag to take a shot of a portion of the screen, or press <kbd>Space</kbd> to select a specific window. Add <kbd>Control ⌃</kbd> to the mix to copy to to the clipboard.

You can view and change these in the Keyboard pane of System Preferences, under the *Keyboard Shortcuts* tab:
[image]

Comment: sweet!  I also found the app, it has the somewhat obscure name of 'grab'

Comment: The app is borderline useless, it does exactly what the short cuts do but in a gui rather than short cuts

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX Which makes it useful to people like my mom who don't like to use or memorize keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: And to people like me, who have been using Macs since the 1980's, but can't keep up with which keyboard shortcuts have changed this year.  :P

Comment: opening grab every time isn't much easier lol