# Change screenshot keyboard shortcut to a single key

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, screen-capture

I want to set my keyboard shortcut for `Copy picture of selected area to clipboard` to the `END` key. Literally just the single keypress `END`.

I tried looking at [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/132984/keyboard-shortcuts-with-a-single-key), but wasn't sure neither what the Bundle ID was for screenshots. If it's a global screenshot, I also don't know the key that `defaults` expects...

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/56171/313842 see if the accepted answer works.

Comment: I tried to set one of those shortcuts to a single key. It doesn’t work.

Comment: It only works with F keys. It does not work with `END`. The post I linked in my question has a way to add single key shortcuts. I just don't know the bundle ID nor the name of the entry that the plist would expect. I'm pretty sure the bundle is `com.apple.screenshot`.

Comment: There was a file in `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screencapture.plist`. See if helpful. also, CMD+ shift+ .  will let you see global preferences file in the same folder. I locked it before opening it and unlocked it after closing to prevent changes. Could I suggest you an edit to add these comments to the question? Then we can purge them.

Comment: The `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.screencapture.plist` I have is completely empty.