# iTunes doesn't open and give a blank message

Tags: itunes, macos

I've been having troubles with iTunes : 
it was working yesterday morning, and after I restarted my computer it will no longer run, it just gives me an empty message box

[image]

and if I leave it for a moment an error appears:

[image]

The problem occurred when I was on a old version of OSX, so I updated to Sierra and to the newest version of iTunes as well, didn't change a thing.
What I have tried :

1. restart computer
2. Install Sierra with iTunes 12.5.4
3. Try to remove iTunes, I just have a message : iTunes can't be modified or deleted since Mac OS requires it
4. Try and download iTunes from the Apple website : the available one was 12.4.3, so when I try to install it tells me a newer version is already installed and stops.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pro Tip:- Rather than Cmd/shift/3 for a full screenshot, if you use Cmd/shift/4 then tap the Spacebar & click in the window you want, you'll get a picture of only that window, with a nice drop-shadow too. I trimmed the existing shots for you.

Comment: @Tetsujin Oh my gosh best tip ever.

Comment: There's a QA on it, all the alternatives - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3822/how-do-i-take-a-screenshot-on-my-mac

Answer (score 1):

Exploratory troubleshooting: try holding the Option (or Alt) key down while you launch iTunes. Hold it until you see the following:

[image: Choose iTunes Library]

Now press "Create Library…" and see if you have any more success.

As a second option, try creating a new user on your system and see if iTunes works any different/better there.

These are steps to help you determine if the problem is the iTunes *application* or if it's something specific to your user account and its data.

Comment: Thanks for answering me.
I tried holding the alt key but I have the same result

Comment: Have you run a quick Malwarebytes' Anti-Malware (MBAM) for Mac scan?